# Add and mention some pages in another page

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arrows, two-column, block

How can I add some pages in another page like the following picture,
[image: sample]

and how can I mention them with this free arrows on the text!

Comment: I am sure the above was done manually. Someone took image copies the 4 pages, and added arrows, may be using indesign or photoshop to make the above page.

Comment: but its vectorized, how could it possible.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "its vectorized". You could take an image of pages, put them one one page, and add arrows and text. You can do this in MS Visio for example, indesign, etc... Any graphics app will allow you to do these things. The above is just a marketing page, and these things are done manually. Not automated. Are you asking for a Latex solution? Maybe if the images are there, this could be done using Tikz. But it seems to be this is something that can be done more easily using a graphic app.

Comment: Thanks for answering, my means from "vectorized" is as i zoomed it, it didn't lose its quality of text and even I can select mini pages' photos easily, by the way if I use photo of the page it won't change if I change the source page and this is one big problem.

Comment: Final image being vectorized has nothing to do with how it was made?  This depends on how the final image was saved. If it was saved as svg or pdf then it is vector graphics if png it is bitmap, etc... desktop publishing systems can save to many graphics formats.

Comment: It looks like a poster were they "input" some pages of a long pdf...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution. This one uses a `tcolorbox` for including images with shadows (like in your example), tikzlibrary `tikzmark` for references inside the text and tikzlibrary `calc` for placement inside images.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzmark{A}
\lipsum[1]


\begin{tcbraster}[blankest, overlay, remember as=first, drop fuzzy shadow, raster columns=1]
\tcbincludegraphics[graphics options={page=13}]{MemoirChapStyles}
\end{tcbraster}

\begin{tcbraster}[blankest, overlay, remember as=second, drop fuzzy shadow, raster columns=1]
\tcbincludegraphics[graphics options={page=21}]{MemoirChapStyles}
\end{tcbraster}

\lipsum[3]
\tikzmark{B}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,line width=1mm,draw=red!75!black]
\draw[->] (first.center) to[bend right] (second.center);
\draw[->,green] (pic cs:A) to[out=30,in=120] ($(second.north west)!.3!(second.east)$);
\draw[->,blue] (pic cs:B) to[out=30,in=120] ($(first.north west)!.6!(first.south)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple node to include the page as an image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % For dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cp{7cm}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]
\node[draw,rounded corners,inner sep=0]{\includegraphics[width=4cm,page=156]{pgfmanual}};
\end{tikzpicture}
& \kant[1]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]