# \hangindent does not behave correctly in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I'd like to obtain a similar effect as in the picture below: a shaded box with paragraphs that are indented after the first line.
I've tried to use \tcolorbox, but hanging indents do not behave correctly in that environment for some reason:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,width=5in,center upper,
drop fuzzy shadow southeast,
boxrule=0.4pt,sharp corners,colframe=black!80!black,colback=white!10]

\medskip

\begin{center}Works Cited \end{center}

\hangindent1cm{
Abrams, Robert E.. Landscape and Ideology in American Renaissance
Literature: Topographies of Skepticism. Cambridge: Cambridge UP, 2004.
Print.}

\hangindent1cm{Agamben, Giorgio. Homo Sacer: Sovereign Power and Bare
 Life. Trans. Daniel Heller-Roazen. Stanford: Stanford UP, 1998.
 Print.}

 \end{tcolorbox}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you think this is a duplicate ? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316809/add-and-mention-some-pages-in-another-page

Comment: Have you got access to PDF files of your resources ? Why are you working with images ?

Comment: I just want to create the effect of an embedded document within my document, with a drop shadow. As I said above, using images is not ideal. I was hoping to just code this somehow and avoid using images altogether. Also: my attempt to use \tcolorbox reveals a problem with the package: it doesn't allow hanging indents to work properly for some reason.

Comment: Your code works for me!

Comment: What about this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11272/faded-drop-shadow-using-tikz-based-rounded-rectangle

Comment: @Ignasi each line receives an increasing indent with my code. It should have a hanging indent.

Comment: It is very easy to blame the package when your code doesn't do what you want, but it is not always wise. The contents of your box is centred because that's the default. There's nothing wrong with the hanging indents. At least, not when I compile your code, though it is admittedly hard to discern that without switching the alignment to something more suitable.

Comment: @cfr Nice of you to defend the package, but I guess tcolorbox will stoically bear to have been falsely accused. ;-)

Comment: My most humble apologies to the creator(s) of \tcolorbox! I stand duly reprimanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\hangindent` does what it should, but you have additionally activated centering (`center upper` is one of the parameters of the `tcolorbox`). As you can see, your lines are centered, but the lines after the first one are additionally indented by `1cm`.

Start your box with

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,width=5in,%center upper,
drop fuzzy shadow southeast,
boxrule=0.4pt,sharp corners,colframe=black!80!black,colback=white!10]
```

(`center upper` has been deactivated by comment sign), and you get

[image]

Comment: Ah! Thank you. My LaTex skilz are limited. This makes perfect sense.